# S7 Edge SD Card

Tags: sd-card

Okay, so i changed my 256 GB SD card into adoptable storage, worked fine and had all my data. Now I formatted my phone and the phone says I have to format the sd card and erase data. And when I put the sd card into my laptop all the files are blank. All I need are my images, please advise!

Comment: Did you format the sd card?

Comment: That's because of encryption you can try decrypt adopted sd card only from linux based OS (ubuntu..) search for that on google. Or if it isn't encryption than, connect sd card to PC via SD card reader, and than see what disk digger or other file recovery software can find. Try second solution first it is easy than decrypting. And next time when performing factroy reset, backup files :)

Answer (score 0):

> And when I put the sd card into my laptop all the files are blank

By this I assume you mean that there is no content on the SD card?

If this is the case, it means that your SD card has somehow been formatted or the index has been damaged in some other way.

> All I need are my images, please advise!

You can most likely recover many if not all of your images. **Do not write anything to the SD card now.** Instead, get a program like photorec, Recuva or Disk Drill for your desktop computer and use it to recover the images from the SD card.